# How to customize UAModalPanel

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have seen a very nice sample code for [UAmodalPanel](http://code.coneybeare.net/uamodalpanel-an-open-source-modal-panel-alter) as the link below. But after i downloaded the code, i do not know that how to implement in my project.

[image]

i need to implement above screen alone in my project, and also i need to perform action if we tap the any row in tableview. if anyone knows please help me out.

Comment: Are you want to do this action when user tap cell rather then the UIButton m i right?

Comment: No i want to show this screen for UIButton action only, after displaying this table i need to perform action for when user tap the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Example Few Bugs then also i guide to you,

Follow step to get the tap event

In UAExampleModelPanel.h following code use.

```
    #import "UATitledModalPanel.h"

    @interface UAExampleModalPanel : UATitledModalPanel <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>//Implement UITableViewDelegate.
 {
        UIView          *v;
        IBOutlet UIView *viewLoadedFromXib;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *viewLoadedFromXib;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title;
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

    @end
```

In UAExampleModelPanel.m following code use.

Implement Following code into - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title

```
        UITableView *tv = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        [tv setDataSource:self];
        [tv setDelegate:self];  //Implement Following statement for the set delegates.
```

Now implement the Delegate method of the UItableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

It may helping to You.

Comment: Thanks  for your response samuel, you are almost correct but tableview is not displaying in that pop up view by following your code.

Comment: That's bug into example so it's not implemented into Example :-P

Comment: I implemented following code into  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title                     UITableView *tv = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        [tv setDataSource:self];
        [tv setDelegate:self];
        
        
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UAExampleView" owner:self options:nil];
  
  NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tv, nil];
  
  //int i = arc4random() % [contentArray count];
  v = [[contentArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];

        
        [self.contentView addSubview:v]; now its working fine

Comment: Can change the border color black into any other color? if it is possible where should i edit the color? please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of UAModalPanel. If you read through the [README](https://github.com/coneybeare/UAModalPanel) found on the main page, it clearly shows how to customize the panel, including borderColor. There is also a sample project which shows exactly how to implement what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this  [LeveyPopListView](https://github.com/jerometonnelier/LeveyPopListView)  sample code. its also also same like UAModalPanel, LeveyPopListView is simple and easier to understand by following this sample i achieved what i want.